# Is it possible to deserialize data that looks like JSON (but isn't) using serde_json?

Tags: json, rust, serde

I have a hard time deserializing (using Rust's `serde` and `serde_json` v1.0) the following JSON I receive:

```
{
    ["string content"]
}
```

The object's array is *not* identified by a key, so the following doesn't work:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Data {
    key: Vec<String>
}
```

I've also tried using `#[serde(flatten)]` on the `key` field but I get an error:

```
can only flatten structs and maps (got a sequence)
```

The data I receive doesn't look like valid JSON. Is it still possible using `serde_json`?

Comment: That is not valid JSON.

Comment: Since this is not valid JSON you can not deserialize it with serde_json but maybe you can try to parse it with [nom](https://github.com/Geal/nom)

Answer (score 1):

The input you show is not valid JSON. You will not be able to use serde_json to deserialize that input because serde_json only accepts JSON.

If you find out what format the data is intended to be in, consider using (or writing) a Rust library dedicated to that specific format.